# How to grep square brackets in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to grep [0](including square brackets) in a file using perl, I tried following code

```
my @output = `grep \"\[0\]\" log `;
```

But instead of returning [0], it is giving output where it matches 0

Comment: The problem is that you need to escape the backslashes once for Perl, once for the shell and once for regex. But the solution is to not use an external command (`grep`) to do something Perl is really good at.

Comment: why call shell command grep? perl is great in work with text files and regexpes ... and this can help you: https://perlmaven.com/how-to-grep-a-file-using-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to escape the `[` and `]` twice, as `[ ... ]` has a special meaning in regexes (it defines a character class).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @output = `grep "\\[0\\]" log `;

print for @output;
```

But you really don't need to use the external `grep` command. Perl is great at text processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  print if /\[0\]/;
}
```

My solution reads from any file whose name is given as an argument to the program (or from `STDIN`).